# How would about a dozen 50 ft to 1,400 ft (approx. 15 m to 430 m) giants wandering around a continent affect seismic activity?

Tags: physics, geology, earthquake, giant

8 of the giants would be around 50-100 ft (15-30 m) and only one would be 1,400 ft (430 m), the other three would be about 500-800 ft (152-243 m). Let's say that they are somehow remarkably light for their size, so the 50 ft giants weigh about 50,000 tons, and are quadrupeds (I'm not sure that this is necessarily even possible, but I'm going to pretend it is). They move maybe 100 miles in a year. How much destruction/earthquakes would this cause?

I want these giants to cause some mayhem when close to a settlement, but not make the surrounding areas completely unlivable for humans. How could I adjust their size/movement to accomplish this? Or, is it unrealistic to have them walking in the first place? Sorry if I haven't given enough details I don't really know all the factors that would matter in this situation.

Comment: 50,000 tons for a 50ft giant proportioned roughly like a human is not remarkably light, it's 100x denser than lead. Do you mean 50,000 kg? That would also not be remarkably light, but it would be about the same density as a person - assuming a 50kg person is about 5ft tall, so increasing their height by a factor of 10 should increase their mass by a factor of 1000.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think I meant pounds. That's about 22,000 kg, I think? I'm very bad with numbers and also very American.

Comment: What does a 1400 foot tall giant use for bones? Steel, cement, stones, none of them will be strong enough. They can do for compression to make a building that tall, but they won't do for walking.

Comment: On the 'not make surrounding areas unliveable' point, I think what you've described would mostly be massively inconvient but not unsurviveable. If it's doing 100 miles a year, that's about quarter of a mile a day. So you see them coming, and probably have the chance to pick what's important, have a moving on party, notify the neighbours and move out. I guess it's consuming everything it moves through, it may even be possible to steer them away from your village by creating desolate patches that won't sustain it. Burn the ground in front of it so it heads off towards food?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the effects on the enviroment if a Giant walked by in a world with Earth like physics?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102473/what-would-be-the-effects-on-the-enviroment-if-a-giant-walked-by-in-a-world-with) (I only found that one question, but I'm 85% sure there have been others. Note that the only difference between your Q and that one is scale. Scale is overcome with increased seismic sensor sensitivity. In other words, your critters will simply cause less damage - but the same kind of damage nonetheless.)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of geological mass they're still very small. I don't think they'd cause earthquakes. You would feel the vibrations when they moved nearby, but that's not an earthquake.

I think they would cause havoc. They'd trample houses and crops, presumably eat everything too. In winter they could start avalanches and in summer rockslides. I don't think it's earthquake stuff though.

Comment: Someone should calculate the actual magnitude when one is nearby

Comment: I don't think you could really calculate it. It's going to depend on how the creature lifts and puts down its feet. Given it's extremely slow speed it could be picking them up and putting them down extremely slowly leading to very limited vibration and shock. But if it's taking a giant bound and then stopping to eat everything in reach for the rest of the day it's a different story. Equally, if it moves along rivers and swamps it's going to be very different than if it prefers to plant its feet on bare rock. Basically, what's the terrain and how does it actually move?

Comment: https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/energy-hurricane-volcano-earthquake3.htm  If you work out the equiv energy produced by a footstep, you could make an estimate of the earthquake equiv magnitude.   https://news.climate.columbia.edu/2021/09/08/a-morning-that-shook-the-world/  The collapse of one tower of the WTC produced about a 2.1 mag. So a WTC sized giant walking would be in the range of round-about-1.